# putExtra doesn't send the extras

Tags: android

I'm trying to send some extras to the next activity, but it simply does not work and I dont understand why. I'm populating a map with overlays and when clicked I try to send the ID of the overlay item to a new activity I get CursorIndexOutOfBounds.

```
  public static String ROW_ID = "row_id"; // Intent extra key

 protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // return super.onTap(index);


    ROW_ID = overlayItemList.get(index).getTitle();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewContactFromMap.class);
    intent.putExtra("ROW_ID", overlayItemList.get(index).getTitle());

    Log.e("putExtra", "ROW_ID is " + ROW_ID);

    context.startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

Here Log.e outputs the id of the item that's clicked. Example 29.

But in my next activity I try to open the Log.e, but it shows the value 0 and that's why I get the CursorIndexOutOfBounds. But why isn't it picking up the value 29?

```
        // get the selected contact's row ID
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    rowID = extras.getLong(MyOverlays.ROW_ID);

    Log.e("ViewContactFromMap", "rowID is: " + rowID);
```

Even if I hardcode and set the ROW_ID to 29, I still get the value of 0 in my next activity

---

After the help I got from these people below, I got it to work with this:

```
    ROW_ID = overlayItemList.get(index).getTitle();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewContactFromMap.class);
    intent.putExtra("ROW_ID", overlayItemList.get(index).getTitle());

    Log.e("putExtra", "ROW_ID is " + ROW_ID);

    context.startActivity(intent);
```

---

```
        // get the selected contact's row ID
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    rowIDs = extras.getString("ROW_ID");

    rowID = Long.parseLong(rowIDs); 
    Log.e("ViewContactFromMap", "rowID is: " + rowID);
```

Comment: What's the value of MyOverlays.ROW_ID?

Comment: hmm. that actualy gives the correct value. il try to work something with that :)

Comment: Well, you should probably not use statics to transfer data between Activities, I was more thinking since you're setting the value with the key "ROW_ID", you also need to getLong with the key "ROW_ID". See @MikeGates answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.putExtra()`, you are putting the String "ROW_ID".  Thus, you need to grab the data from the String "ROW_ID" in your next activity in `getExtras()`.

Note that your variable `ROW_ID`'s value is "row_id", but you are placing the value into "ROW_ID". Try using all uppercase or all lowercase - these things are case sensitive.

Explanation: you are storing a variable using `.putExtra()` into the tag "ROW_ID". Then, in the other activity, you are trying to grab the value using `.getLong()` from the variable `ROW_ID`, whose value is "row_id".  Do you see the problem now?  Value stored as "ROW_ID", trying to receive it as "row_id"...  these tags are not the same.  As a result, `.getLong()` cannot find the value and thus just makes it 0.

Short answer: change your variable to `public static String ROW_ID = "ROW_ID";` and ensure that the variable you are really trying to get is a long.  If you're storing an integer, use `.getInt()` instead, or `.getString()` for a String.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes around ROW_ID `intent.putExtra(ROW_ID, overlayItemList.get(index).getTitle());`

or

Change the case of ROW_ID `public static String ROW_ID = "ROW_ID";`

**EDIT:**
Also make sure your types are the same.  `getTitle` may actually be a `String`.  In that case `getString(MyOverlays.ROW_ID)` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: That would just set the key "29" to the value "29", note that ROW_ID is changed in the code.

Comment: `putExtra` takes a key/value pair. The issue is that your key isn't the same. Use `ROW_ID` for the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String ROW_ID = "row_id"; // Intent extra key
private Context c;  

 protected boolean onTap(int index) {
Intent intent = new Intent(c, ViewContactFromMap.class);
                    intent.putExtra(ROW_ID, overlayItemList.get(index).getTitle());
                    c.startActivity(intent); 
}


// get the selected contact's row ID
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    rowID = extras.getLong(MyOverlays.ROW_ID);

    Log.e("ViewContactFromMap", "rowID is: " + rowID);
```

Answer (score 0):

overlayItemList.get(index).getTitle()); is probably returning a string and you are using

```
rowID = extras.getLong(MyOverlays.ROW_ID);
```

I am unsure but try the following

```
rowID = extras.getStringExtra(MyOverlays.ROW_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Intent in = new Intent(this, XXX.class);`
`in.putExtra("testExtra", "TestData");`
`startActivity(in);`

Same problem happened to me. And I solved this problem adding following :

`Intent in = new Intent(this, XXX.class);`
`in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`
`in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`
`in.putExtra("testExtra", "TestData");`
`startActivity(in);`